# Como salvar arquivos binários em python?

Tags: python

Sou novo no SOPt e gostaria de saber como faço para salvar e abrir arquivos binários em python.

Se possível gostaria de ver exemplos de como isso é feito e o que os parâmetros significam.

Comment: Olá Alysson, traduzi sua pergunta, visto que este site é em Português. Também removi as tags [tag:script] e [tag:mysql] já que elas não parecem ter relação com a pergunta. Se por algum motivo eu alterei o que você quis dizer, basta editar a pergunta com as correções que você considera cabíveis.

Comment: Existe o modo `b` para abrir um arquivo de forma binária; `rb` para leitura, `wb` para escrita.

Answer (score 2):

Todo arquivo é uma sequência de bytes, sendo assim, **todo arquivo é *"binário"***. A **única coisa** que você consegue armazenar em um arquivo são `bytes`.

Seja lá o que for que você está pensando em salvar em um arquivo, vai **ter** que converter em bytes primeiro.

Muitas vezes se quer armazenar frases, como `"Olá, sou um arquivo"`, dentro de arquivos, porém, arquivos **só aceitam** `bytes`...

Para resolver isso, foram criadas codificações que representam as letras em forma de bytes:

```
 >>> frase = "Olá, sou um arquivo"
 >>> binario = frase.encode('utf32')
 >>> print([byte for byte in binario])
 [255, 254, 0, 0, 79, 0, 0, 0, 108, 0, 0, 0, 225, 0, 0, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 
  115, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 0, 117, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 117, 0, 0, 0, 109, 0, 0, 0,
  32, 0, 0, 0, 97, 0, 0, 0, 114, 0, 0, 0, 113, 0, 0, 0, 117, 0, 0, 0, 105, 0, 0, 0,
  118, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 0]
```

Neste exemplo a frase foi encodificada usando `utf32`, gerou 80 `bytes`, que podem ser escritos em um arquivo de forma binária:

```
 with open('arquivo.txt', 'wb') as f:  # 'w' para escrita e 'b' para modo binário
     f.write(binario)
```

O detalhe que geralmente confunde é que o python, a partir da versão 3, trabalha por padrão com a **codificação automática**. Se você abrir o arquivo sem colocar a letra `'b'` no modo, ele vai **encodificar e decodificar automaticamente** para você todo o texto que for escrito ou lido, convertendo de/para `bytes` de forma transparente!

```
with open('arquivo.txt', 'w') as f:  # sem o 'b' abre em modo "texto"
    f.write(frase) # escreve a frase direto, o python resolve!
```

Neste exemplo ele vai usar `utf-8` para codificar que é o padrão, mas caso queira pode usar outra codificação:

```
with open('arquivo.txt', 'w', encoding='utf32') as f:
    f.write(frase) # vai codificar automaticamente em utf32
```

Da mesma forma, se você ler o arquivo binariamente, ele vai retornar `bytes`, porém, se ler em modo texto, o python vai decodificar os bytes automaticamente e te devolver uma string:

```
with open('arquivo.txt') as f:
    frase = f.read() # já retorna str
    print(frase)
```

Resumindo: **Todo arquivo é binário e armazena bytes**, o que muda é a forma como você vai tratá-lo. Se abrí-lo em forma binária, vai ter que ler e escrever bytes, caso abra em modo texto o python cuida da codificação e você pode lidar com strings diretamente.