# Como mandar imagens via socket em Python?

Tags: python, imagem, socket

Assim está o servidor:

```
import socket
from PIL import Image
port = 8000
host = '127.0.0.1'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)



while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Conectado a {}'.format(addr))
    with open('logo_python.png', 'rb') as f:
        conn.send(f.read())
        l = f.read()
    #im = Image.open(l)
    #im.show()
        f.close()

print('Arquivo enviado')
```

E o cliente:

```
import socket
from PIL import Image
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

print("Recebendo Dados...\n")
with open('recebido.png', 'wb') as f:
        print('file opened')
        print('Recebendo dados...')
        data = s.recv(4000)
        f.write(data)
        print(data)
        print("ENVIADO")
        f.close()
with open('recebido.png', 'rb') as f:
        im = Image.open(f)
        im.show()

print('Transferência completa!!!')
s.close()
print('Conexão encerrada.')
```

O erro que aparece:

```
    File "C:/Users/Diego Cândido/PycharmProjects/servarq/ClienteTeste.py", line 18, in <module>
    im = Image.open(f)
  File "C:\Users\Diego Cândido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2618, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
  File "C:\Users\Diego Cândido\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 172: character maps to <undefined>
```

Basicamente o que o servidor está mandando para o cliente é:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02Y\x00\x00\x00\xcb\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00]\xc9\x86&\x00\x00\x00\x04sBIT\x08\x08\x08\x08 #... e assim por diante
```

Comment: O erro que você postou está incompleto - só colocou a linha do erro, sem o traceback completo. O traceback seria útil para saber onde exatamente o erro está ocorrendo. Você pode [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/343302/edit) a pergunta e acrescentar.

Comment: Você está fazendo `print(f.read())` e em seguida `conn.send(f.read())` porém `f.read()` só funciona uma vez, na segunda vez ele retorna nada, porque o arquivo já foi todo lido. Se quiser usar o conteúdo do arquivo duas vezes, você tem que armazenar em uma variável, rebobinar o arquivo ou abrí-lo de novo.

Comment: Vou corrigir e colocar o novo erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Agora com o código e o erro ficou bem mais fácil ajudar.

`UnicodeDecodeError` ocorre quando se está tentando transformar em string uma sequência de bytes que não combina com a codificação utilizada.

Pelo texto do erro, parece que ele está usando a codificação charmap cp1252; Isso só ocorreria se você estivesse tentando rodar o método `.decode()` ou se tivesse aberto o arquivo em modo texto (e não binário); Quando você abre um arquivo em modo texto, [o python faz a decodificação automática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/343237/como-salvar-arquivos-bin%C3%A1rios-em-python/343283#343283).

No código que você colou na pergunta tem a letra `'b'` no `open`, que indica modo binário:

```
with open('recebido.png', 'rb') as f:
```

Para verificar se houve algum engano, fiz um teste com um arquivo JPG que baixei [aqui](https://graph.facebook.com/250313002551410/picture?type=large), chamei de `diego.jpg`. Abri ele em modo texto, sem a letra `b`:

```
>>> f = open('diego.jpg', 'r', encoding='cp1252') # sem o 'b'
>>> f.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 383: character maps to <undefined>
```

Como pode ver o erro foi bastante parecido com o seu - acredito que ao testar, deve ter confundido os arquivos e deixado o `open()` sem o `b`, e por isso recebeu o erro que colou, não consigo ver outro motivo.

Resolvi então **testar o seu código acima**, porém com esse arquivo `diego.jpg` que baixei. Troquei somente o nome do arquivo de `logo_python.png` para `diego.jpg` e rodei o servidor.

Troquei o nome do arquivo de `recebido.png` para `recebido.jpg` e rodei o cliente. Deu o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cliente.py", line 19, in <module>
    im.show()
#  ( ... )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1982, in show
    _show(self, title=title, command=command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 228, in load
    "(%d bytes not processed)" % len(b))
OSError: image file is truncated (3 bytes not processed)
```

Como pode ver, 4000 bytes não é o suficiente para transferir a imagem. Editei mais uma vez o cliente, e aumentei o número para 6502 (que é exatamente o tamanho da imagem `diego.jpg`):

[image: deu certo!]

Resumindo: Deu certo, seu código está "funcionando", o erro que você está tendo é impossível de ocorrer com o código da forma que você colocou na pergunta, deve haver algum engano. A única coisa que mudei foi o número de bytes, que deve ser exatamente o tamanho da imagem, pois com menos bytes não é possível abrir a imagem.

Comment: Fiz o que você disse, mas ainda aparece o erro: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'

Comment: Modifiquei para 6000 bytes, mas ainda dá o mesmo problema.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Diego Cândido/PycharmProjects/servarq/ServidorTeste.py", line 20, in <module>
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(g))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'

Comment: @DiegoCândido isso significa que `g` no seu erro não é uma variável contendo bytes, e sim um `BufferedReader`. O tipo da variável que você passa para `io.BytesIO()` tem que ser `bytes`, caso contrário dará esse erro que você falou. Tente `print(type(g))` para ver qual o tipo da sua variável.

Comment: Não é possível ler imagens parcialmente, nem 1024 nem 6000 nem 100000 bytes, é preciso ler a imagem **toda**, TODOS os bytes.

Comment: O tipo é <class '_io.BufferedReader'>. O problema é que não sei o que mandar para o cliente. Pois se envio "g", dá esse problema, porque ele pede bytes. Mas se eu mando socket.send(g.read()), lá no cliente, ele também dá erro. Não sei como mandar a imagem e não sei como o cliente deve receber e mostrar, pois ele passa como bytes.

Comment: @DiegoCândido   Mas de onde você tirou esse `g`?? No código que você colocou, não tem `g`! Coloca o seu código verdadeiro na pergunta, e o erro completo, **por favor**!! Senão fica muito difícil acompanhar e ajudar.

Comment: Você pode [Editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/343302/edit) a pergunta e acrescentar informações

Comment: Feito! Atualizei o código.

Comment: @DiegoCândido ficou show! Agora só colocar o erro completo, com traceback

Comment: cara, consertei o código e está dando um erro parecido com o seu: OSError: image file is truncated (3 bytes not processed)

Comment: Como você fez para descobrir o tamanho exato da imagem?

Comment: Descobri! Cara, muito obrigado mesmo, deu tudo certo. Não tem noção do quanto você me ajudou. Vlw!!!!